Wrap an Existing Android App inside My App -Android Studio
Lets say there are 2 apps, A and B
App A is already available on google play store, consider it as an messaging app
App B is an app that will be created by me, conside it as an calculator app or something similar to that
Now the question is, is it possible to wrap the App A in the app that i created App B
Now I don't want to release this app to google playstore or something, I just want to create this app for my privacy
I want the App A to be opened whenever i enter a secret code in the App B and fucntion normallyThanks in Advance!
I explained my idea, I am expecting a solution for this idea

Your app B could raise an intent that would launch some activity from app A into your application's activity stack., and possibly provide parameters that make it behave differently than it normally does. What you can do depends on what intents app A is registered to receive. And this would not prevent app A from also being accessible through its normal launcher intent.
